Is it possible to programmatically buy USDT?
I am hoping to use my bank's API to detect deposits in fiat and then purchase USDT from some service. I haven't been able to find a service that can enable this. Is anyone aware of a way to automate the purchase of USDT? To be clear, a simple automatic buy of a set amount isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking to automatically purchase variable amounts based on the amount of fiat deposited to my bank account.
